# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\server\htdocs\file.php using if() and elseif() statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using this code:

```
<?php
include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = file_get_html("http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php");
foreach ($dom->find('tr') as $node) {
if (is_a($node->children(0), 'simple_html_dom_node')) {
    if ($node->children(0)->plaintext == "Protection") {
        $plain = explode(',', $node->children(1)->plaintext);
    if($plain[0] === null){echo 'Nu are';}
     elseif($plain[0]!== null) {echo $plain[0];
     if($plain[1] === null){echo 'Nu are';}
     elseif($plain[1] !== null) {echo $plain[1];} 
     }  
    }

    }
}

?>
```

All i want is if there exist $plain[x] or $plain[y] to shows me if not to display an custom text (in my case 'Nu are'). All is fine, code works good because $plain[1] not exist in present case, but I receive an error too.

Here is the result receved from code:

`Corning Gorilla Glass 2
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\server\htdocs\preluare\1.php on line 10
Nu are`

First is shows me offset 0, because exist and second offset not exist and shows me that error and after error is the correct custom text.

Correct result is `Corning Gorilla Glass 2
 Nu are`

Comment: Look at the right panel titled "Related" - there are HEAPS of the same question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: print_r($explode); and echo count($explode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$plain[1] !== null
```

use

```
array_key_exists(1, $plain)
```

or

```
isset($plain[1])
```